# BAD EXC in [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:* beforeDate:*];

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to do some stress testing on my app with a unit test, and I'm running into some problems. Below is my code:

```
    //Stress test api and core data
__block BOOL done = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
    DLog(@"in here");
    [viewController createList:testList
                       success:^(Lists *list) {
                           DLog(@"in success block : %d", i);
                           STAssertNotNil(list, @"list is not nil");
                           done = (i == 99);
                       }
                       failure:^(NSError *error) {
                           DLog(@"in fail block");
                       }
     ];        
}

@autoreleasepool {

    while (!done) {
        // This executes another run loop.
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
}
```

The problem is, after several iterations, I get a **bad access error** on the line

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

I've already put the `while` loop in the `@autorelease` because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672359/ios5-crashes-during-runmodebeforedate). I'm using **ARC** on the project, so I don't know if that's contributing to the problem..? I need to use the `NSRunLoop` to force the unit test to wait for the block to complete.

Has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: When you have a crash, **always post the backtrace**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a similar situation, I did it differently and it worked fine. What I did was in the main test, used dispatch_group_async to the normal queue, and then in the main test waited for the group to finish. That works just fine and you don't mess with the unit test's runloop.

if for some reason the above is not acceptable, then try not using any autorelease pool to see if that works If it does, then move it into the while look. With ARC the need for an autorelease pool is greatly diminished. You can observe memory usage using Instruements too.